# get all javascript variables string values using python

Tags: javascript, python, html, variables

With the above code i would like to search for radio web streams inside a web page. The code is using javascript and python.

**get_variables_values.js**

```
var all_variables = [{name:"window",completed:false}];

var exclude_variable_names = ["window.self","window.document","window.name","window.customElements","window.history","window.menubar","window.scrollbars","window.statusbar","window.toolbar","window.status","window.closed","window.frames","window.length","window.top","window.parent","window.navigator","window.origin","window.external","window.screen","window.innerWidth","window.innerHeight","window.scrollX","window.pageXOffset","window.scrollY","window.pageYOffset","window.visualViewport","window.screenX","window.screenY","window.outerWidth","window.outerHeight","window.devicePixelRatio","window.screenLeft","window.screenTop","window.defaultStatus","window.defaultstatus","window.styleMedia","window.performance","window.crypto","window.indexedDB","window.webkitStorageInfo","window.localStorage","window.alert","window.atob","window.blur","window.btoa","window.cancelIdleCallback","window.captureEvents","window.clearInterval","window.clearTimeout","window.close","window.createImageBitmap","window.fetch","window.find","window.focus","window.getComputedStyle","window.matchMedia","window.moveBy","window.moveTo","window.open","window.postMessage","window.print","window.prompt","window.queueMicrotask","window.releaseEvents","window.requestIdleCallback","window.resizeBy","window.resizeTo","window.scroll","window.scrollBy","window.scrollTo","window.setInterval","window.setTimeout","window.stop","window.chrome","window.launchQueue","window.caches","window.cookieStore","window.scheduler","window.getScreens","window.isMultiScreen","window.showDirectoryPicker","window.showOpenFilePicker","window.showSaveFilePicker","window.originPolicyIds","window.speechSynthesis","window.originAgentCluster","window.trustedTypes","window.crossOriginIsolated","window.openDatabase","window.webkitRequestFileSystem","window.webkitResolveLocalFileSystemURL","window.getComputedAccessibleNode","window.getwindowSegments","window.exclude_variable_names","window.exclude_variable_names_length","window.pointer","window.all_variables","window.TEMPORARY","window.PERSISTENT","window.location","window.locationbar","window.personalbar","window.clientInformation","window.isSecureContext","window.sessionStorage","window.storageFoundation"];

var exclude_variable_names_length = exclude_variable_names.length;

var pointer = 0;

function find_variable_first_level(){
    var variable_name = all_variables[pointer].name;
    var level_variable = eval(variable_name);
    var variable_type = find_data_type(level_variable);
    if(variable_type==="undefined"){
        all_variables[pointer].completed=true;
        pointer+=1;
        return 1;
    }else if(variable_type===null){
        all_variables[pointer].completed=true;
        pointer+=1;
        return 1;
    }else if(variable_type=="string"){
        all_variables[pointer].completed=true;
        pointer+=1;
        return 1;
    }else if(variable_type=="number"){
        all_variables[pointer].completed=true;
        pointer+=1;
        return 1;
    }else if(variable_type=="boolean"){
        all_variables[pointer].completed=true;
        pointer+=1;
        return 1;
    }else if(variable_type=="array"){
        for(var array_key in level_variable){
            var array_element_name = variable_name+"["+array_key+"]";
            if(is_built_in_function(array_element_name)==false){
                all_variables.push({name:array_element_name,completed:false});
            }else{
                all_variables[pointer].completed=true;
                pointer+=1;
                return 1;
            }
        }
        all_variables[pointer].completed=true;
        pointer+=1;
        return 1;
    }else if(variable_type=="object"){
        for(var b in level_variable) {
            if(variable_name.includes(b)==false && b.includes("window")==false ){
                var name = variable_name+"."+b;
                if(eval(variable_name+"."+b)!=null){
                    if(is_built_in_function(name)==false){
                        if (typeof eval(name) != "function") {
                            all_variables.push({name:name,completed:false});
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        all_variables[pointer].completed=true;
        pointer+=1;
        return 1;
    }
}

function is_built_in_function(name){
    for(var i = 0; i<exclude_variable_names_length;i++){
        if(name.includes(exclude_variable_names[i])){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


function find_variables_alpharthemitc(){

    while(all_completed()==false){
        success = find_variable_first_level()
    }
    variable_strings = fetch_only_alpharthemic_variables();
    return variable_strings;
}



function fetch_only_alpharthemic_variables(){
    var alpharthemic_variables = []
    var all_variables_length = all_variables.length;
    for(var i = 0; i<all_variables_length;i++){
        var variable_data_type = find_data_type(eval(all_variables[i].name));
        if(variable_data_type=="string"){
            alpharthemic_variables.push(eval(all_variables[i].name));
        }
    }
    return alpharthemic_variables;
}

function all_completed(){
    var all_variables_length = all_variables.length;
    for(var i=0;i<all_variables_length;i++){
        if(all_variables[i].completed==false){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function find_data_type(one_variable){
    if(Array.isArray(one_variable)){
        return "array";
    }else{
        if(typeof one_variable === "string"){
            return "string";
        }else{
            if(typeof one_variable === "boolean"){
                return "boolean";
            }else if(typeof one_variable === "number"){
                return "number";
            }else if(one_variable===null){
                return null;
            }else if(typeof one_variable === "object"){
                return "object";
            }else if(one_variable === "undefined"){
                return "undefined";
            }
        }
    }
}
find_variables_alpharthemitc();
```

**search_peradio_new.js**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebView , QWebPage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from search_peradio_ui import *
import sys
import re
import requests
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal

class Scrap_Peradio:
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        
        self.mainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.main_ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.main_ui.setupUi(self.mainWindow)
        self.mainWindow.show()
        
        self.url = "https://www.peradio.com"
        #self.url = "https://synpasitoisagiois.radio12345.com/"
        
        self.main_page_fetch_page(self.url)
        
        sys.exit(self.app.exec_())
        
    def main_page_fetch_page(self,url):
        print("Step 1")
        self.browser = QWebView()
        self.main_page = QWebPage()
        self.browser.setPage(self.main_page)
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl(url))
        self.main_page_loaded = False
        self.browser.loadFinished.connect(self.main_page_html)
        
    def main_page_html(self,ok):
        
        if(self.main_page_loaded==False):
            if(ok):
                self.main_page_loaded = True
                
                #get code
                javascript = "document.documentElement.outerHTML"
                html_code = str(self.browser.page().currentFrame().evaluateJavaScript(javascript))
                self.step_2(html_code)
                
    def step_2(self,html):
        print("Step 2")
        self.urls_main = self.find_urls(html)
        #radio_streams = self.step_3()
        #if(len(radio_streams)>0):
        #   print(radio_streams)
        #   return 1
        #else:
        #   self.step_4()
        self.step_4()
        
    def find_urls(self,string):
        regex = r"(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))"
        url = re.findall(regex,string)      
        return [x[0] for x in url]
        
    def step_3(self):
        print("Step 3")
        radio_streams = []
        counter = 1
        total = len(self.urls_main)
        for url in self.urls_main:
            try:
                print("Parsing url "+str(counter)+"/"+str(total))
                counter+=1
                sub_page = requests.get(url,timeout=10)
                header = sub_page.headers
                if("Content-Type" in header):
                    content_type = header["Content-Type"]
                    if("Content-Length" in header):
                        try:
                            content_length = int(header["Content-Type"])
                        except Exception as e:
                            content_length = 0
                    else:
                        content_length = 0
                        
                    if(content_type=="audio/mpeg" and (content_length<=0)):
                        radio_streams.append(url)
                else:
                    continue
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error")
        return radio_streams
        
    def step_4(self):
        print("Step 4")
        f = open("get_variable_values.js", "r")
        javascript_code = f.read()
        f.close()
                
        #get string variable values
        javascript_variables_values = str(self.browser.page().currentFrame().evaluateJavaScript(javascript_code))
        print(javascript_variables_values)
                    
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    program = Scrap_Peradio()
```

The execution of self.step_4 --> `print(javascript_variables_values)` is `None`.
If there is any kind of javascript error how do I know about?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? If you need to manage data as a collection, put it in an object of your own, don't use global variables.

Comment: @Barmar I need it as the post says for web scraping. Details: input url web page, output web radio stream if exists. For sites like www.peradio.com the web radio stream is inside a javascript variable (`MP3_JPLAYER.pl_info[0].list[0].mp3`)

Comment: Where does the question say anything about web scraping? And if you're scraping a remote page, its variables won't be loaded as local variables.

Comment: @BarMar check the update. I want to run some javascript using python and PyQtWebKit.

Comment: @Barmar code updated.